# Most suitable Unix platform for developing device drivers

Tags: device-driver

I completely newbie in device drivers, so I hope my question is in place, but I need to develop a driver to control some equipment. I was thinking on using Linux as the host OS, but not sure if it is such good idea. I've heard some horror stories about the mess of developing device drivers under Linux. Is there a better alternative under the *Nix world? Or maybe should I check other OSes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux documentation is basically non-existent (similar to other platforms). However, there are a few books which do cover enough information to get started, and the trickier kernel bits can borrowed from other drivers (yay for Open Source).

However, it is one of the easiest current platforms to develop drivers for. There are cleaner models, such as QNX, but that product is sadly near the end (and doesn't support 1/10th as much as hardware as Linux)

What type of device is the driver targetting? Many times you can avoid writing in-kernel drivers (for instance, using libusb in userspace, or the user space IO framework)

Comment: I think the device would be controlled thru serial port

Comment: @bugspy.net: if it's just a serial port device then why do you think you even need a driver ?

Comment: @bugspy.net: There is no need for a system driver then. Open the serial port ("/dev/ttySx" where X is the right port) and have fun reading and writing to it.